# How to send a message over presentModalViewController to a UIViewContoller(login) that Button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So here is my problem:

I have an AppDelegate with a navigationController:

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

In there i put an presendModalViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
 [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:passwordViewController animated:YES];
```

}

I want an PasswordView which takes the Password and tells the UIView in the NavigationController that he can begin his work with catching information from the internet, with a nice MBProgressHUD Loading View.

I tried to build up an Delegate but it does´t work because the instance of my UIView is build up in the Navigation controller.

I there a way to tell my UIView which is in my NavigationController that Password was given and back that the Password was right und say back with:

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to remove this View?

There is an App named iOutbank which has what I want to assume...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim Dean, thank you very much you helped me to help myself and think about my problem.
So this is how i ended up doing it:

I made an instance of my PasswordView in My tableView:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
{

self.passwordView = [[PasswordViewController alloc]init];
[passwordView setPasswordViewDelegate:self];

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.passwordView animated:YES];
}
```

Put in there my Delegate:

```
@interface TableView : UITableViewController <PasswordViewDelegate>
{


PasswordViewController *passwordView;

}
```

And get my Delegate method from my PasswordView:

```
-(void)loginPressed
{
NSLog(@"Login Pressed");
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];



 }
```

And now I can use my logic of my TableViewClass.

I love stack overflow!

Greetings and I hope there is somebody I shall helped with my solved problem, I'm going to sleep now....

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate to your view controller class that is invoked when a valid password has been entered. Something like this in your login view controller would work:

```
@protocol LoginDelegate
    - (void)loginSucceeded;
@end


@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController 
{
    id<LoginDelegate> delegate;
}
```

}

Next, set the delegate of your password view controller to be the app view controller class. To do this your app delegate class needs to implement the protocol you've defined for your login delegate, so in the app delegate header and implementation files:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <LoginDelegate>
{
    // App delegate interface stuff
}

@implementation MyAppDelegate
{
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Create myLoginViewController          

       [myLoginViewController setDelegate:self];

       // Display login view controller           
    }

    - (void)loginSucceeded
    {
        // Dismiss login view controller
        // Do other stuff
    }

}
```

When your app delegate class gets notified that the password has been entered, then you can dismiss the password view controller and do whatever it is you want to do next.

Comment: Wow that was fast!THX a lot,
But i didn't got your idea with: "Set the delegate of your password view controller to be the app view controller class", can you explain me that?

Comment: See the code sample I added and it might make more sense... I left out a bunch of details for presenting and dismissing the password view controller, but hopefully this gives you the idea.

Comment: Oh man you are very fast thanks a lot!!!
I had that idea too, but stuck in the place where my logic is written.
So my PasswordViewController instance is in the AppDelegate, but my logic is written in another Controller, this ViewController lays under the NavigationController and I can't reach it with: [self.navigationConroller.MYOtherViewWhereMyLogicIs loginSucceeded].
Did you get my problem or shall I give you some more Code?
MYOtherViewWhereMyLogicIs is an UITableViewController, thats why its important why I can't set the logic to the AppDelegate....

Comment: I think I get your problem. You will probably need to either (a) refactor your code a bit so that your app delegate class knows directly about the controllers it places into the navigation control, so it can call them directly or (b) see if you can launch the password view controller from down within the navigation controller's view controller that needs it. I think (a) would be cleaner, but hard to say without fully knowing the code structure.

Comment: I solved it I will write my answer soon,because I'm not allowed to by stackoverflow, thanks a lot @Tim Dean